# Bitbucket API: Get workspace object in webhook payload

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-webhook

According to the [documentation of the recent refactoring switch](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/bitbucket-api-teams-deprecation/#webhooks) from user/team-based API to the workspace-based API, webhook payloads will soon have the owner property removed. Also according to this documentation, the webhook payloads already contain the workspace object:

The webhook payloads I receive do still contain the owner object (i don’t really care for that though), but they do NOT contain the workspace object. Is this wrongly documented, do I need to setup the webhook differently than before or what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now an official bug. You can follow the public ticket here:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-20239

In the meantime, I added the workspaceUuid as GET parameter to the URL that the webhook is calling. This way I receive it together with the webhook payload on my server for processing.